# Using cookbook version in chef local mode

Tags: chef-infra

My understanding is that when using Chef client in local mode a cookbook can only have one version - the one currently specified in the cookbook's metadata.rb file. For example when I have a cookbook "my-cookbook" and it's metadata.rb file contains:

```
version          '0.5.0'
```

then I can run

```
sudo chef-client -z -o my-cookbook@0.5.0
```

but I will not be able to run a previous version of this cookbook in local mode.

Is this correct?

Are there any alternatives to work with different versions of a cookbook in local mode?

Comment: You could rename the cookbooks like my-cookbook-0.5.0, but you are limited to a filesystem. Chef Zero would have no way of "seeing" the older versions of cookbooks since they do not exist on disk.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was thinking about this but I guess it will get messy pretty soon. So probably my best option is to create a new branch in git for each version and then after I am done with my changes merge it back into 'master' but keep all the 'version'-branches. Then I could check out the 'version'-branch I want to work with and run chef-client in local mode.

Comment: You could install chef server? Then multiple versions of the cookbook would be available :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using solo or client in local mode you can use Berkshelf or Librarian to handle the version solving and download a flattened set of cookbooks that match the solution. In Berkshelf you would use `berks vendor $PATH` for this. Once you have the vendored cookbook folder, pass that in to solo/client.